# Django How to download files from file system?

Tags: html, django, django-media

I'm trying to make a link to a file path on a Windows server downloadable to the user after they click the file link.

My app displays entries from a result of searching a ticket model. The results on the page include items like:  Ticket number, description, status and a link to a flat file (that is stored on a Windows server network share drive; starting with \server.name\folder A\folder B\folder C\file to download.txt

Note

- \server.name, \folder A and \folder B are a constant
- \folder C (as well as the file to download are dynamic (they location and file name will change)
- users will NOT be uploading files. All files that are downloadable - are already saved to a Windows share.

On the display page/template.html I can list all my values in a table (even a link the the file I'd like to download). However, when I hover over the link at the bottom of the browser I see `file://server.name/folder A/folder B\\folder C\\file to download.txt`.  Yes, the last "slash" is a forward slash while all the others are back slashes (not sure why they are changing?)

When I pass the file address to the template it is formatted like : `\\server.name\\folder A\\folder B\\folder C\\file to download.txt` (I can see that in testing when I just displayed the filepath on the page.

How do you make the link to a file path on a Windows server downloadable  to users that wish to download the file?

.html

```
<body>

<h1><p>Ticket Number: {{ thisincident.IncidentID }}</p></h1>
<h3>Description: {{ thisincident.Description }}</h3>
<h4><p>Full Description</h4> {{ thisincident.FullDescription | linebreaks }}</p>

    
    
       Journal Entry #
       Date
       Person
       Journal Entry
       File Name
    
    
    
    {% for f in je %}
    
       {{ f.JE }}
       {{ f.Date }} 
       {{ f.resource }}
       {{ f.entry | linebreaks }}
       <a href="{{ f.Location }}">Download</a>
    
    {% endfor %}
```

view.py

```
def ticket_view(request, IncidentID):
    file_contents = []
    thisincident = ticket.objects.get(id=IncidentID)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(thisincident.LocationPath):
        for file in files:
            if not file == 'manifest.json':
                path_file = os.path.join(root, file)
                path_file = path_file.replace(thisincident.LocationPath + "\\", "")
                file_contents.append(path_file)
    log_list = parseJElog(thisincident.logfiletoparse)

    data = {
        "thisincident": thisincident,
        "result": file_contents,
        "je":log_list
    }
    return render(request, "ticket.html", data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^homepage/$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^tickets/$', views.tickets, name='tickets'),
    url(r'^ticket/(?P<IncidentID>\d+)$', views.ticket_view, name='ticket'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_BASE_ROOT = "\\server.name\\folder A\\folder B"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(MEDIA_BASE_ROOT, "\\folder B\\")
MEDIA_URL = ''
```

[image]

I'm fairly new to Django so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had a similar issue before. You can follow these steps to solve this. I will split the logic into two functions to make this straightforward and easy.

1, display the tickets

```py
def ticket_view(request, IncidentID):
    thisincident = ticket.objects.get(id=IncidentID)
    log_list = parseJElog(thisincident.logfiletoparse)

    data = {
        "thisincident": thisincident,
        "je": log_list
    }
    return render(request, "ticket.html", data)
```

2, download the file

```py
import os
from django.http import FileResponse

def download_file(request, file_path):
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    file = open(file_path, 'rb')
    response = FileResponse(file)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{file_name}"'
    return response
```

I think this is the code you need, the issue your face can be simply solved by using the `os.path` or you can use `pathlib`. here we are passing the `file path` as an argument into the function and it opens the file in binary mode, creates a FileResponse with the file content, and sets the `Content-Disposition` header to specify the filename for the user to download it.

`Content-Disposition` header is an optional header by the way.

[more about Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

3, update your URLs according to the functions we define above.

4, update your template.

```
{% for f in je %}
        {{ f.JE }}
        {{ f.Date }} 
        {{ f.resource }}
        {{ f.entry | linebreaks }}
        <a href="{% url 'download_file' file_path=f.Location %}">Download</a>
    {% endfor %}
```

5, update your settings

```py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' # edit this to your requirements 
MEDIA_ROOT = '\\server.name\folder A\folder B\folder C'  # Windows server path

# make sure that you also serving media files in the URL
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I hope this solution helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the help and detail in this solution. I used it exactly as you presented and it worked!  Thanks again.